# Select number of customers in some interval

Tags: mysql

I have 2 rows like in example below.

[image]

I want to select how many customers I have in some intervals of consumption. 
Example: 1000-3000, 3000-5000 ...

This is my sql query:

```
SELECT t.consumption, COUNT(DISTINCT t.id) as numberOfCustomers <br>
FROM( 
SELECT customer.id, SUM(order.value) AS consumption 
FROM order <br>
INNER JOIN customer ON order.customerId = customer.id 
GROUP BY customer.id) AS t 
GROUP BY t.consumption
```

Comment: Use the `LIMIT {from}, {to}`

Comment: Any ideas? Yes, please add sample data and expected result as text to your question (or sqlfiddle)

Comment: @P.Salmon Expected results:
consumption     numberOfCustomers 
1000-3000                3
3000-5000                1
5000+                       2

Answer (score 0):

You can create a range with this function:

```
CONCAT((FLOOR(t.consumption/2000)) * 2000, '-', 
       ((FLOOR(t.consumption/2000)) * 2000) + 1999) -- the step is 2000
```

and then make your sum group by this range